# Prove that $\int_0^\infty e^{-a^2 s^2} \cos(2 b s) \,\mathrm ds=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2a}e^{-b^2/a^2} $

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Prove that 
$$I(a,b)=\int_0^\infty e^{-a^2 s^2} \cos(2 b s) \,\mathrm ds=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2a}e^{-b^2/a^2}\quad a>0 $$
I can prove it by differential-equations technique(taking the derivative with respect to $b$ to become a first-order equation) but I wanna prove it directly.

Comment: Not so clear, since you will still only have an $s$ under the cosine. If you had an $s^2,$ you would be cooking with gas. But does $\cos$ not suggest a real part of something?

Comment: Use complex analysis.

Comment: Try writing cosine as the real part of a complex exponential and complete the square in the exponent..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the integrand is an even function in $s$, then we can write the integral as

> $$ I(a,b)=\int_0^\infty e^{-a^2 s^2} \cos(2 b s) \,\mathrm ds = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a^2 s^2} \cos(2 b s) \,\mathrm ds.$$

Now, Follow the steps

i) use the identity $ \cos(t)=\frac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}{2}.$

ii) complete the square of the argument of the exponential.

iii) use [Gaussian integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral).

Answer (score 4):

Note that we can complete the square and get the following integral:

$$\frac12 \Re{\left [\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} ds \, e^{-a^2 s^2} \, e^{i 2 b s} \right ]} = \frac12 e^{-b^2/a^2} \Re{\left [\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} ds \, e^{-a^2 (s-i b/a^2)^2} \right ]}$$

We can prove that the integral on the RHS is simply $\sqrt{\pi}/a$ as you may expect (and hope) by using Cauchy's theorem.  Consider the integral

$$\oint_C dz \, e^{-a z^2}$$

where $C$ is the rectangle in the complex plane having vertices at $-R-i b/a^2$, $R-i b/a^2$, $R$, and $-R$ (in that order).  This contour integral is equal to

$$\int_{-R}^R dx \, e^{-a^2 (x-i b/a^2)^2} + i \int_{-b/a^2}^0 dy \, e^{-a^2 (R+i y)^2}\\+\int_R^{-R} dx \, e^{-a^2 x^2} + i \int_0^{-b/a^2} dy \, e^{-a^2 (-R+i y)^2}$$

By Cauchy's theorem, the contour integral is zero.  On the other hand, in the limit as $R\to\infty$, the second and fourth integrals above vanish.  Thus,

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, e^{-a^2 (x-i b/a^2)^2} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, e^{-a^2 x^2} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{a}$$

The result follows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this standard trick:
$$
I(a,b)^2=\left[\int_0^\infty e^{-a^2 x^2} \cos(2 b x) \,\mathrm dx\right]\,\left[\int_0^\infty e^{-a^2 y^2} \cos(2 b y) \,\mathrm dy\right]
$$
Use Eulers formula to convert this all to an exponential integration and use polar coordinates in the double integral
$$
I(a,b)^2= \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty  e^{-a^2 (x^2+y^2)} \cos(2 b x) \cos(2 b y) \,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$$